# Evaluating integration

Tags: integration

We have to solve the following integration . $\int \frac{\sqrt x+1}{\sqrt x(\sqrt[3]x+1)}\text{d}x$

I am not getting any idea how to solve it .

I am not getting anything to substitute

Comment: try getting rid of the radicals by noticing that the lowest multiple of powers to achieve this is $2\times 3$ or $x = t^6$. try this sub then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

---

We have $$I =\frac {1}{6x^{\frac {5}{6}}} \int \frac {6(\sqrt{x}+1)(\sqrt [3]{x})}{\sqrt [3]{x}+1} \mathrm{d}x $$ Now if $u=\sqrt [6]{x}$ then we have $$I =\int \frac {u^2 (u^3+1)}{u^2+1} du =\int (\frac {u-1}{u^2+1} + u^3-u+1) \mathrm{d}u $$ Hope you can take it from here.